# IE width 100% doesn't work. How to fix it?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This code won't work in any IE browser:

```css
main {
  position: relative;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div></div>

</main>
```

I tried using `width 100vw` but horizontal scroll appears if page doesn't fit the viewport. A tried something like width calc(100vw - vertical_scroll_width) but it is not okay if there is no vertical scroll on the page.

Comment: Could be IE isn't recognising `main` as a block level element. What happens if you add `display:block` to `main`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Partial support refers to only the  element (added later to the spec) being "unknown", though it can still be used and styled."
As shown here : https://caniuse.com/#search=main

Main is not fully supported. You can still style it through.

As explained before, simply do :

```
main {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make your `main` element block (in IE it's not block by default):

```
main {
  display: block;
}
```